# Upgrading Ruby to 1.9

Tags: ruby

I have ruby v 1.8 installed at C:\Ruby and its gems underneath.
I am planning to upgrade to v 1.9 , and it's installer try to default the app to c:\Ruby 1.9

How shall i proceed in order not to break my old gems .. including Rails , etc?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to update the question title to emphasize that you're talking about Windows.

Comment: oh and mladen is right. please update your question and tags to include "windows" and "ruby installer".

Answer (score 2):

**Using the RubyInstaller, can I install Ruby 1.8 and 1.9 at the same time?**

**A: Yes**. By using the RubyInstaller, Ruby 1.8 will be installed by default
to C:\Ruby, while 1.9 will be installed to C:\Ruby19. This is by design as
Ruby 1.8 and 1.9 offer a different API that may interfere with some RubyGems.

Source: http://wiki.github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/faq#dual_install

So go ahead and **use the default of installing to C:\Ruby19**.